# How to preserve the error message that is thrown during a 500 internal exception using restTemplate

Tags: java, spring, rest, resttemplate, http-status-code-500

I want to know what is best practice to preserve error messages when calling several micro services that is chained: I have an angular front end that calls a back end rest service which calls another rest service which calls another 3rd party service.

The 3rd party service is somewhat unreliable. And I want the response from that service to be propagated to my front end.

So to make it easier for the sake of demo’ing the problem.

I have a control class in downstream project (separate micro-service/application)

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/my-down-stream-service")
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "my-method")
    public MyCustomResponse method1() {
       //Some complex logic that catch exceptions and propogates a nice little message
       throw new RuntimeException(“This is my exception that indicates what the response is to my 3rd party service”);
    }
}
```

On the other micro-service calling the service above I have a restTemplate making the call to the above service

```
public MyResponse doIt() {
    try {        
       restTemplate.postForEntity(“MyUrl…”, req, MyResponse.class);
    } catch (final HttpStatusCodeException ex) {
        //If I add a break point and inspect the exception here
    }
}
```

[image]

I can see it is a 500 internal exception that gets send to the front end.
If I go and get the `ex.getResponseBodyAsString()` I get back a JSON map with the actual detail of the exception.

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-05-06T22:17:08.401+0200",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "java.lang.RuntimeException",
    "message": "This is my exception that indicates what the response is to my 3rd party service",
    "path": "…"
}
```

And I can convert this into a map and get the message portion and construct a new exception and throw that

```
new ObjectMapper().readValue(ex.getResponseBodyAsString(), HashMap.class).get("message")
```

But this seems like a lot of work that needs to be implemented where ever I need this.
Is there a better way of doing this?

I also tried creating my own HttpStatus - Like a 550 with my "Own custom message". But you cannot set the message for the HttpStatus code dynamically aka at Runtime. Not even sure if this is the correct venture or path to go down.

**My solution in the end based on Amit's suggestion**

I finally ended up creating a custom class that extends springs `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`. If this is on the class path of your springboot app it will intercept the exception before returning it from the controller. I also created my own exception. Reason being this way if I want my functionality to trigger I fire my own exception and everyone else can still follow the normal way. It can be changed at any time.

Also on the client side I had to cast the exception's getBody() JSON to my exception. But I didn't knew if it was my exception to start of with. So I also added some HTTP header. And on the client side I check if that header is present then I know the body is my exception and I could comfortable convert the JSON to my exception.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyRestResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = {MyCustomException.class})
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleConflict(final MyCustomException ex, final HttpServletResponse response) {      
        if (!response.containsHeader("MYTAG")) {
            response.addHeader("EX_TYPE", "MYTAG");
        }

        //here you can go wild as to what type of or just the normal 500
        //return ResponseEntity.status(ex.getHttpStatus()).body(ex); // 500 internal exception
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(ex);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I would like to create a controller advice to handle all kind of exceptions. Then I would like to create a ErrorMessage class which will have custom errorCode, errorMessage fields as per requirements. From this controller advice, for any kind of exceptions occurred in application, it will create an instance of ErrorMessage with details like errorCode and errorMessage and wrap into ResponseEntity object (with HTTP status) and return to the other microservices.

At consumer end check the response status and act accordingly.

Comment: Thanks I added the solution that I went with or at least the server side part based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer you are looking for is creating an implementation of [ExceptionMapper](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ExceptionMapper.html). The interface is designed to handle java exceptions that map to Response.

In your case, if the 3rd part throws an exception which is handled by the ExceptionMapper implementation you can access the error message and return that in the response.

```
public class ServiceExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<ServiceException>
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(ServiceException exception)
    {
        //grab the message from the exception and return it in the response
    }
```